# download a file from a linux google cloud server into my pc

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have some pdf's into linux server and I want to download them into my pc. I am trying to use somthing like this

```
scp username@instance_name:/path_to_this_file/XXX.pdf C:\Users\username\Desctop
```

but isn't working, do you have any idea how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you include in your question the errors you're receiving.

`scp` is a *nix command (not Windows) and so you likely can't use that command on Windows.

See: [Transferring files to (from) Linux VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp)

If you have a Linux shell (e.g. WSL) then the easiest way is probably to use [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) which provides a wrapper around `scp` for you.